# Scope ORDER BY overwriting everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-order-by

I've set a default_scope to display my recipes in my application. It should as a default show all that are 'live' and order them by created_at.

```
default_scope ->{ where(live: true).order("created_at DESC") }
```

This works fine but when I try to display my recipes with an order of likes count (another column in the database)

```
<% @recipes.order("likes_count desc").limit(16).each do |i| %>
  <%=link_to image_tag(i.image(:fixed), alt: "MUC", :class => "newest-recipes"), i %>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't seem to want to work. I think the default_scope is overriding it? I can change the order of the scope and that will change it but if I remove the scope all together, the order still doesn't want to work.

Anything I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the SQL queries in your log as they come in (I frequently `tail -f log/development.log` as I develop). You should see that both orders are at the end of the SQL query, but the default scope always comes first. Pretty sure it's always going to override it.

Comment: It seems to be showing this: `SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."live" = 't' AND (created_at > '2014-01-13 00:00:00.000000') ORDER BY created_at DESC, created_at desc, likes_count DESC LIMIT 12`

Comment: Any way I can override so that likes_count comes first?

Comment: You can use `reorder`, which will override the `default_scope` ordering. Though, I would suggest getting rid of the default scope ordering so that you can be more explicit in the views in which it's used. Up to you.

Comment: reorder is perfect. The default scope has been very hand and it is just in one instance I need this to work so I think reorder will work. Thanks very much for your help!